# How do I troubleshoot and improve this slow running query?

Tags: performance, mongodb, indexing

I'm looking to fine tune a string search query that I am using on Mongo.  In the SQL Server world, I'd like to believe I have a decent understanding of how indexes work and how to build proper indexes.  I tried giving it a shot with Mongo, but, I don't believe that I'm not going about it the right way.

My collection has roughly 4.3 million documents.  The document structure looks like this:

```javascript
{
   "_id":{
      "$oid":"527027456239d1212c07a621"
   },
   "ReleaseId":2451,
   "Status":"Accepted",
   "Title":"Hard Rhythmic Motions",
   "Country":"US",
   "MasterId":"35976",
   "Images":[
      {
         "Type":"primary",
         "URI":"http://api.discogs.com/image/R-2451-1117047026.jpg",
         "URI150":"http://api.discogs.com/image/R-150-2451-1117047026.jpg",
         "Height":307,
         "Width":307
      },
      {
         "Type":"secondary",
         "URI":"http://api.discogs.com/image/R-2451-1117047033.jpg",
         "URI150":"http://api.discogs.com/image/R-150-2451-1117047033.jpg",
         "Height":307,
         "Width":307
      }
   ],
   "Artists":[
      {
         "_id":2894,
         "Name":"DJ Hyperactive"
      }
   ],
   "Formats":[
      {
         "Name":null,
         "Quantity":1
      }
   ],
   "Genres":[
      "Electronic"
   ],
   "Styles":[
      "Hardcore",
      "Acid"
   ]
}
```

I am executing a case insensitive search on one of the top-level document properties and on one of the nested document properties:

```javascript
db.releases.find({$or: [{Title: new RegExp('.*mozart.*',"i")},{'Artists.Name': new RegExp('.*mozart.*',"i")}]})
```

I tried creating an index; when I execute `.getIndexes()` I can see the index I created:

```javascript
{
    "v" : 1,
    "key" : {
            "Title" : 1,
            "Artists.Name" : 1
    },
    "ns" : "discogs.releases",
    "name" : "Title_1_Artists.Name_1"
}
```

At this point I thought that I would be all set.  However, the query ends up taking between 28 and 32 seconds to execute.  I tried calling `.explain()` to get a little more insight:

```javascript
{
    "cursor" : "BasicCursor",
    "isMultiKey" : false,
    "n" : 4098,
    "nscannedObjects" : 4292400,
    "nscanned" : 4292400,
    "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 4292400,
    "nscannedAllPlans" : 4292400,
    "scanAndOrder" : false,
    "indexOnly" : false,
    "nYields" : 29,
    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
    "millis" : 29958,
    "indexBounds" : {

    },
    "server" : "lambic:27017"
}
```

From my limited knowledge of Mongo, this looks like a table scan which is why the query isn't performing very well.  However, I don't know how to make this query better!  I would expect that the index that I created to cover this query, but, that must not be the case.

Now, the last thing I want to point out is that this is certainly not on the most robust server.  The hardware specs (including CPU and RAM) are very limited.  However, if my analysis is correct and I'm doing a table scan, there must be some performance improvements I can make on the Mongo side.

Comment: I can tell you it is the regexes that are the problem, they can't use an index

Comment: @Sammaye - Even if I remove the wildcard at the beginning of both regular expressions I still don't get an index only query (according to `explain`).  Although, it does look like the execution time drops ~6-8 seconds.  Are there other changes I can make?

Comment: What if you test each clause of the or?

Comment: @Sammaye - I actually just tried that.  I created two separate indexes; one for `Title` and one for `Artist.Name`.  I then executed the query with just one of the conditions and I still don't get an index only query.  I am starting to wonder if my indexes are corrupt.  When I created the indexes I am getting a `Connection reset by peer` error.

Comment: hmm it is possible, can you drop them and try again?

Comment: could you not try to define a [fulltext index](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-text-index-on-multiple-fields/)? A text search should be more efficient. Creating the index will probably take a lot of time and storage space, but it may be worth it. See this link: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/text-search/

Comment: @w0lf I wouldn't recommend saying to use features which are not production ready to be honest

Comment: @Sammaye It was just a wild idea, and the scenario described by the OP seems to be the perfect use case for fulltext search. It's good to know that MongoDB's Fulltext implementation is no yet production ready. I was expecting it to be, I didn't see any warnings on the website.

Comment: @w0lf it is a good idea its just fts is not production ready, yeah not sure why they took the warnings off but there are a number of JIRAs that will change its core soon

Comment: There is no problem with your indexes, problem is just that regex search in mongodb can't use indexes efficiently. For getting higher performance you should just remove the indexes.

Comment: "indexOnly" refers to the need to read the data file in order to get additional fields to create the response object. If you execute a find using only indexed fields but you select all fields to be returned, you never will get a "indexOnly=true".

Comment: @SamuelGarcía - That's what I discovered! I actually changed the way I stored the data to make it easier to query and to achieve an index only query.  I just need to find some time to add an answer describing how I handled the problem (and what I learned for any other Mongo newcomers like myself).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone for the responses.  I wanted to follow up on this question since it had a few votes and to make sure anyone who stumbles upon this page in the future knows what I ended up doing.

The fulltext index sounds like a great solution.  However, because this is only a small side-project of mine I'm not willing to throw more hardware at the architecture (the fulltext index requires a good amount of disk space for 4 million records).

What I ended up doing is flattening my data structures to make them easier to query *and* removed the wildcard search so that my indexes on that new structure can actually be used.  By doing this I can achieve an indexOnly query (although the performance still isn't amazing, I find it to be adequate given my weak hardware stack).

Answer (score 0):

A fulltext index is probably what you need. You could also parse the document before inserting it, and put the keywords in an array inside the document and index this array.